# can i insert some specific fields from one table to a class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

is it possible insert some specific fields from one table to a class in mvc?
for example i have tbl_User . can i insert just field "Name" in "MyClass"?
i wanna pass a model(MyClass) to view that contains some fields of tbl_User . 
and i used codefirst.

```
    public class MyClass:tbl_User 
    {
           //i mean can i put some fields of tbl_User instead below code .
          //but below code insert all fields of tbl_User
        public List<tbl_User> tbl_User { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can; see the code below.

```
// get /users
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new YourContext())
    {
        // We just need to show user name and id will be used to perform actions like edit user ETC. So we have created a reduced model named UserIndexModel.
        return db.Users.Select(u => new UserIndexModel { Id = u.Id, Name = u.Name}).ToList();
    }
}
```

Model definitions:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HashPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
public class UserIndexModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and now i should have s.th like this in view? : @model MyProject.Models.SetOfClasses.UserIndexModel

Comment: @niknaz since Index action is returning a collection of users, you need to declare it as `@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.SetOfClasses.UserIndexModel>` in the view

Comment: when i use your way i get this error on this line of cod " @Html.Action("LogOn","Account")"  .  : Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: my logon is PartialView .[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
        {

            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {
               
                var AllFeatureToLog = db.tbl_profile.Select(u => new UsersClass.LogOn {                 username = u.username, password_User = u.password_User });
                return PartialView(AllFeatureToLog);
            }
        }